# Get stuck on the oracle.sql.Array to String Array when using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, spatial

I am using JDBC to develop a spatial database app, now I have problem in retrieving the coordinators of the polygons I inserted into the database, what I got is an oracle.sql.Array with base type Number, and my idea is to get the coordinators into an String array and get them one by one to paint on the map

**SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES**

> NUMBER(79,68,184,125,179,133,189,138,139,229,131,225,127,233,21,175,26,168,18,163,67,73,74,76)

**Following is my code:**

```
try{
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 String fetchBuidling = "select a.shape.sdo_ordinates from buildings a";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(fetchBuidling);

 while(rs.next()){
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
    Array coordsInfo = rs.getArray(columns);
    String[] vertice = (String[]) coordsInfo.getArray();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < vertice.length; i++){
    System.out.println(vertice[i]);
    }  
}
```

The error is `"java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.math.BigDecimal; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;"`;I used the block of code from Oracle's document, though the second getArray() makes no sense to me since it mentioned in this case coordsInfo should be a logical pointer, the link is 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html#retrieving_array

But without the second getArray() I can not even compile the code, can any one help, I am really frustrated on this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typecasting all the resulting values of the column into a String array, you could cast it to an Object array.  Later check for the columntype using

`metaData.getColumnType(int column)`

If the columnType is of type NUMERIC, then you might want to extract it as a `BigDecimal` and call a `toString()` on it to convert it to a `String`

**Evil hack (don't tell anyone I suggested this):**

```
    Object[] vertice = (Object[]) coordsInfo.getArray();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < vertice.length; i++){
       System.out.println(vertice[i].toString());
    }
```